# What military aircraft is in this video still?

Tags: aircraft-identification, plane-spotting

I found this image of an aircraft on a video by a friend of mine and I would like to have your help identifying this for me:

[image: image showing a silhouette of a military aircraft]

Comment: Usually you can find them parked at military bases.

Comment: Also helps to say at least approximately where your friend saw this, particularly since it's a military plane, and different militaries in different parts of the world have different planes.

Answer (score 38):

That looks like the [Lockheed Martin F-35](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_Martin_F-35_Lightning_II).

[image: F-35 image]
<sub>[Image source](https://images.app.goo.gl/M96pdWpknZFebysn8)</sub>

Comment: I was going to say F-15, but the jet inlets give it away.

Answer (score 17):

[image: chinese j31 v f35]

It seems that the chinese copy of F35 can be distinguished by exhaust type.. The picture is an F35 i presume

Comment: The J-31 is twin-engined, like the F-15 which also has a similar silhouette from below

Comment: @ChrisH: Interesting, yeah it's also similar.  But the ends of the F-15 wings aren't parallel to the fuselage, they taper back inward aft of the wing-tip.  That was another difference I noticed besides the twin vs. single engine.  e.g. google found http://clipart-library.com/clipart/6cyorayzi.htm and http://www.milart.com/product/m_misc_986.html . Also, the F-15's trailing edge is perpendicular to the fuselage, vs. F-35 having a reverse sweep to the trailing edge all the way in.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, there are plenty of differences, but (to me) the number of engines is the most obvious - counting a small number vs comparing angles, which depend a bit on viewing angle.  The J-31 shares the F-35's pointy intakes and the F-15's engine layout, so for the initiated or those with images to compare it's easy to tell them apart.

Comment: @ChrisH: For sure, number of engines is the most definitive and easiest to be sure of.  And good point about other features being dependent on viewing angle.  I mostly just commented to record the results of looking for other differences (between F-15 and F-35), in case you or anyone else was curious.